# How to migrate a realm database to an app group?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Really excited about the recent addition of sharing Realm data between apps and extensions. The documentation details how to set the default realm to the app group directory, I've got that working.

Here's what I'm stuck on -- what's the best way to transfer the old database to the new location in the app group?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just move the file using NSFileManager?

Comment: Apple suggests avoiding file coordination API's, as data can get corrupted: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2408/_index.html

Comment: Since only your app will be able to move it, and you can do so atomically, you'll be fine

Comment: Sounds good, that seems to work. Mind checking the answer to make sure it's the proper approach?

Comment: in iOS 8, you can try BusinessObject as a CocoaTouch Framework. Put your business entity and data in the BusinessObject is a good practice I think.

Comment: @Solomon I can't seem to find anything on BusinessObjects. Do you have a link to documentation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on @segiddins comment, I decided to go with moving the old database to the app group using NSFileManager:

```
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    //Cache original realm path (documents directory)
    let originalDefaultRealmPath = RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath()

    //Generate new realm path based on app group 
    let appGroupURL: NSURL = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroup")!
    let realmPath = appGroupURL.path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("default.realm")

    //Moves the realm to the new location if it hasn't been done previously
    if (fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(originalDefaultRealmPath) && !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(realmPath)) {

        var error: NSError?
        fileManager.moveItemAtPath(originalDefaultRealmPath, toPath: realmPath, error: &error)

        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        }
    }

    //Set the realm path to the new directory
    RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(realmPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help other reader.

As discussed in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4490, you can set app group path with below code and use File Manager to move existing db as mention above.

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()
config.fileURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroupIdentifier)!.appendingPathComponent(dbFilename)
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Comment: you're not moving an existing Realm DB by setting config's fileURL to a custom path, you're just specifying the path from where the db to be read