# How to transfer Realm database to appgroups

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm, ios-app-group

Hey I have an app that uses Real to persist data. I used the default realm file directory to store the apps data but I would like to move the file directory to app groups in order to create app extensions. Heres my code for changing the file path

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()
config.fileURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.bundle.identifier")!.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

The code changes the file path perfectly, the problem is that the data gets wiped when I change the path, since the data at the previous path isn't being transferred.

Someone else had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996999/how-to-migrate-a-realm-database-to-an-app-group), but it's very outdated and didn't work

I've tried methods of transferring it such as this, but all as failed

```
 migrateData(){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    //Cache original realm path (documents directory)
    let originalDefaultRealmPath = realm.configuration.fileURL?.absoluteString

    //Generate new realm path based on app group
    let appGroupURL: NSURL = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.groupIndentifier")! as NSURL
    let realmPath = appGroupURL.path!.appending("default.realm")

    //Moves the realm to the new location if it hasn't been done previously
    if (fileManager.fileExists(atPath: originalDefaultRealmPath!) && !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: realmPath)) {
        do{
           try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: originalDefaultRealmPath!, toPath: realmPath)
        }
        catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }

    let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: appGroupURL.absoluteURL)
    //Set the realm path to the new directory
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!  I'm still fairly new to Swift and programming in general so excuse me if I'm being clueless.

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a file from one path to another? `NSFileManager.default.copyItemAtPath(_:toPath:)`? Also, remember that Realm stays connected to it's file, so either move the file before you start 'talking' to realm or ensure realm calls are in an autorelease pool so those objects are released before connecting it to a new file.

Comment: @Jay I just tried that, it threw an error that a file already exists there. I also tried deleting that file but it says I don't have sufficient permissions

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jay's answer, I was able to answer my own question. In case anyone else needs help, heres what I did:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let originalPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!

    let appGroupURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.bundle.identifier")!.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
    do{
        try fileManager.replaceItemAt(appGroupURL, withItemAt: originalPath    )
    }
    catch{
    print("Error info: \(error)")
    }
```